# Error then trying to multiply two arrays by using '@'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to multiply two arrays by using '@' but this is the error I get

```
a@b
```

[unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'list' and 'list'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwwiK.png)

I read that '@' is used for matrix multiplication, which is what I need

Comment: Lists are not arrays. NumPy arrays support `@`. Lists do not.

Comment: You could convert Lists to numpy arrays then multiply. Else do it element by element using a loop or comprehension, optionally using zip().

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it appears as though you are using `lists`. You need to use `arrays` for which you can use the `numpy` module like this:

```py
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [10,20,30,40]

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

z = x@y
print(z)
```

which returns this:

```
300
```

If you want to multiply lists without `numpy` you can do this:

```py
# method 1
z = 0
for i, v in enumerate(x):
    z = z + (x[i]*y[i])
print(z)

# method 2
z = sum([x*y for x,y in zip(x,y)])
print(z)
```

Both would return the same value as above...

Comment: Beware that your method using `enumerate` may generate an `IndexError` if the lengths of the lists are not the same.

Comment: @Chris,  yes, this would be true for all 3 methods (including `numpy` arrays). that would be a check that the user would need to do beforehand if they were at risk of that...  `len(x) == len(y)`.

Comment: `zip` will not risk that.

Comment: @Chris,  true, but the user then risks multiplying lists of different lengths accidentally without receiving an error (so a potential semantic error)...  but point taken.

Comment: If you're on python3.10+, `zip(..., strict=True)` to avoid calculating dot product of incompatible vectors.